# Video game where you play a miniature female demon with regular handgun (but large compared to her)

Tags: story-identification, video-games

A few years back (around 2015-2017, I think), I ran into a game on Steam that sounded interesting, but not enough for me to spring for the full price. The gameplay shown in the video had a miniature female demon holding a regular size handgun (larger than she was) running around a house and attacking some set of enemies. It was a 3D game with cel-shaded graphics. The impression I got at the time was that it was the sort of game where you're overwhelmed by a large number of weaker enemies to gun down rather than more sophisticated opponents. I didn't think to add it to my Steam wishlist. I want to say the name was two words, something like "Gun Demon". It is not *Gun Devil*, which is more of a 2D platformer while this one was 3D, running around the floor of the house (probably with some ability to jump to higher levels). It was a 3rd person (I'm not even sure it was over-the-shoulder camera) perspective, and I think there was the ability to move camera around the protagonist with the mouse or right joystick.

I can't swear to it, but I think that it may have been one of those "adult" games with saucy cutscenes in between the action. Again, never got a chance to play it, but that's what my brain is pushing toward.

I'll include more details if they come to me, but that's all I can recall at the moment.

Comment: Was the perspective first-person, third-person/over-the-shoulder, isometric, top-down, etc?

Comment: @RoamingShroob: I never got a chance to play it, but I got the impression it was a free camera set-up using the mouse.

Comment: Could it be Hedon Bloodrite or Wildcat Gun Machine?  Those share a few elements with your description.

Answer (score 1):

Does [TinyShot](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1278760/TinyShot/) look familiar? It's got a tiny player and a big gun relative to them, but nothing else matches unless you somehow saw an alternate player skin that may or may not exist?

Comment: No, this was either 3D, or made to look like it.